# Why was a question looking for easily transportable monitors closed as a shopping question?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

Why was this [question looking for easily transportable monitors](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/125076/1810) closed as a shopping question?

As indicated in the question and illustrated in the comments and the the only answer, this question is not a shopping question, as the OP is not looking for specific goods or services. Instead, there are looking for device types that aren't regular computer monitors but could be used as such (e.g., pico projectors) or some tricks to make regular computer monitors more transportable (e.g., removing the stand).

Answer (score 3):

I've edited your title and reopened your question. Now it doesn't sound like a shopping question, at least to my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it does sound much better now.